# Why Do You Love Me? (Part II)

Tags: cipher, knowledge, metapuzzles

Thank you so much for your help in scoring my [last date](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/66922/why-do-you-love-me). The date went really well, and we have so much fun. However, after that date she didn't reply to my texts for days, only to hit me with this:

[image]

Well, I've been agonizing over them since. Looks like she has upped her difficulty too, after seeing how fast I solve the last one. Can you guys help me one more time with solving these?

Picture 1:

[image]
[image]

*I think* the texts are important, so I'll copy all of them out.

**First picture:**

> **pFWDHMRzRFCYNqvZMluqECfBIfVPKCfOXIZXgENLMjbGRYIhbE**

**Second picture**

> **TENOUEHYNEHDAEDFNPZLITEETAOHREDOEZSKOT**
>
> FINAL MESSAGE:
> **CAUMINHGHLJZAKABBKBQNYXGJNCXYCGJZAEUU**

Comment: I get the "Try Again" message. :/

Comment: I get the same as @Sid, plus another red herring.

Comment: You need to marry this girl. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the puzzle, it was very fun and challenging for my first one.
Here is my answer to the puzzle, first of all, i had almost all done but was missing one word in the crossword. I wasn't exaclty solving it the way @hagfy did it but we ended up with the same answers. Here is my found and the result of the second page :

Cross world clues (copied from @hagfy answer):

> 1. SIXDEGREES - The "Six degrees of separation" variant "Six degrees of Kevin Bacon"
> 2. PORK       - Bacon is salt-cured pork
> 3. BEACON     - Beacon - 'e' = Bacon
> 4. POWER      - This is a Sir Francis Bacon quote
> 5. EGG        - Bacon and eggs (or eggs and bacon)
> 6. SALT       - Bacon is salt-cured pork

1st page top right clue:

> The three pictures are known as a "triptych" art. The word fit the in the box.
> As @hafgy said, if you use a Vigenere cipher, you end up with:
> **wooooops you just stumbled upon a red herring lets try again**

Dots clue:

> Honestly I did not found about this, so here is the @hafgy answer:
> It looks like each border has a pattern of lines with 20 dots, repeated twice on each border. They all looked the same to me.
> If you use the reference of the Crossword result, which lead to Bacon (the triptych art is also done by a certain "Bacon").
> You can use the Bacon cipher decoder with the pattern with the I=J/U=V and you got :
> **"I LIKE U"**

The train clue:

> Here is where I actually found something by myself. As stated, the pictures are:
> **Left**: Small Train Station at Night
> **Middle**: Train in the Snow
> **Right**: The Railway
> All of it are references to train, etc...
> And you can use here the Rail Fence cipher (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rail_fence_cipher) with a Rail key of 3 (the word "Three" being highlighter in the clue).
> Which give you this sentence :
> **thedeadendofonepuzzleisthekeytoanother**
> The Dead End Of One Puzzle Is The Key To Another
> A red herring is also known as a mislead, which can be also seen as a dead end.

The last code:

> I had trouble, finding what it could be.
> I thought first that some "Peacock" cipher exist because of the animal inside the borders.
> But finally, it was only a Vigenere Cipher using the Beaufort variant with the *dead end* key:
> **redherring**, giving this result :
> **textmeyouraddresssowecannetflixnchill**
> Text me your address so we can NetflixNchill

Hurry up man, you got no time left !

Comment: Great work! The paintings in the second puzzle are somewhat of a rebus actually. I cannot include paintings of actual rail fence since it might be too obvious.

Answer (score 3):

Partial answer:

Crossword clues

> All clues seem to be related to **BACON**
>
> ```
> 1. SIXDEGREES - The "Six degrees of separation" variant "Six degrees of Kevin Bacon"
> 2. PORK       - Bacon is salt-cured pork
> 3. BEACON     - Beacon - 'e' = Bacon
> 4. POWER      - This is a Sir Francis Bacon quote
> 5. EGG        - Bacon and eggs (or eggs and bacon)
> 6. SALT       - Bacon is salt-cured pork
> ```

So I went looking for some kind of

> Bacon Cipher
>
> It looks like each border has a pattern of lines with 20 dots, repeated twice on each border.  They all look the same to me.
> Patterns I tried with their decoded values (using distinct codes) are:
> Top dot = 'A', Bottom dot = 'B' -> AABAB BBAAB ABBAA BBAAB -> 'FZMZ'
> Top dot = 'B', Bottom dot = 'A' -> AABAB BBAAB ABBAA BBAAB -> '?GTG'
> Dot = 'A', Space = 'B' -> ABAAA ABABA ABAAA ABAAB AABAA BAABB -> 'IKIJET'
> Dot = 'B', Space = 'A' -> BABBB BABAB BABBB BABBA BBABB ABBAA -> 'XVXW?M'
> *(A '?' means there is no letter matching that sequence)*
>
> <strike>None of the decoded strings seem all that useful, though.  Could be used as a key for something else (especially variations 1 and 3 which all map to letters), or I could have done it wrong.</strike>
>
> **CORRECTION**
>
> I just tried using the third pattern with the I=J/U=V version of the cipher and got **"I LIKE U"** (congrats!).  I think that might be the only message to find here.

"Three Studies for Figures..." picture

> The missing word is TRIPTYCH, which fits in the box.
> And from @GarethMcCaughan, the artist of this triptych is "Francis Bacon".  I assume this bacon just goes up there, with the rest of the bacon.

Character string below that picture

> If you decode it using TRIPTYCH as a Vigenere key, you get:
> **wooooops you just stumbled upon a red herring lets try again**
>
> This might mean the triptych picture and/or this string are unnecessary?
>
> Here's @GarethMcCaughan's actual input (since I screwed it up last time):
> If you take the uppercase letters of the ciphertext as 'A' and lowercase as 'B', it's BAAAAAABAAAAABBAABBBAABAABAAAABAAAAABAAAABBAAAABBA.
> Decipher that bacon cipher to get **REDHERRING**
>
> Two red herrings in one ciphertext!

---

I think that about covers the first half.  The second half contains considerably less success.

---

"Three examples of locomotive...art" picture

> Left: Small Train Station at Night
> Middle: Train in the Snow
> Right: The Railway
>
> Not sure what to do with these.  The word 'Three' is highlighted, so maybe TRIPTYCH is relevant here?  Maybe a ROT3 of *something*?
> I tried using different permutations of the painting names as ciphertext or keys, but nothing turned out all that great.
> Also, they're located in different places: The Met, Musée Marmottan, and National Gallery of Art

Character string below that picture

> No idea.  I tried decoding as a Vigenere cipher with 'BACON', 'TRIPTYCH', 'THREE', 'HANNAH', concatenated painting names, first letters or the paintings, and maybe some others...got nothing.

Final Message:

> I have no idea...I tried several of the same keys as before.

Comment: Pretty sure it won't help solve anything, but you should look up the artist who made that triptych.

Comment: Also worth looking at letter cases of the ciphertext in the first image, though again it won't help solve anything.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Oh geez, totally missed the artist!  I'm thinking it might just be another clue along the same lines as the crossword?  Regarding the ciphertext cases, good call, I didn't consider that.  Thanks!

Comment: I think you missed the point of my comment about case. You can do the Baconian cipher thing on the cases of those letters. (But it just yields "redherring".)

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Yes.  Yes, I did.